# How do we prove that the real numbers have no upper bound

Tags: calculus

I want to use proof by contradiction.

Suppose that real numbers are bounded, then according to the axiom of continuity, there exists a least upper bound $b$.

But if $x\in \Bbb R$, then $x+1\in \Bbb R$ because of the inclusion property of real numbers.

But $x+1\in \Bbb R\Longrightarrow x+1\leq b\Longrightarrow x\leq b-1$, hence $b-1$ is an upper bound for $\Bbb R$.

However since $b$ is a least upper bound we must have: $b\leq b-1\Longrightarrow 1\leq 0$, a contradiction, since $1>0$

Thus $\Bbb R$ is not bounded.

Is that proof correct?

Comment: If $r$ is that upper bound, can you find a way to make a bigger number than $r$?

Comment: hint: consider $r+\pi^{10000000000}$

Comment: yes $r+1>r$ ,so what

Comment: @chris, you assumed that there is a bound r and then found a number that is bigger than this bound, hence you can define a new boundary r+1. For any such bound you can find a number which is bigger than the bound, thus no such bound exists.

Comment: You should clarify: Is it required that the "upper bound" also be a real number? (The negative reals have an upper bound that is not a negative real, so this is a valid question.) In the affine extended real number system, $+\infty$ is an upper bound on the real numbers: it just is not itself a real number. In any system that combines the reals with the transfinite ordinal numbers, any transfinite ordinal number is an upper bound on the reals.

Comment: @chris, first define the meaning of upper bound mathematically. then use $(\text{boundary}+1>\text{boundary})$

Comment: @Daniel, don't go overboard. Just $r + 1$ is enough.

Comment: @vonbrand, don't go overboard. Just $r+\frac12$ is enough.

Comment: You have edited your question to add your work: well done. However, now the question is not clear. Are you asking if your given proof is correct, or something else?

Comment: Your proof looks completely correct. It isn't the proof in the big book in the sky, but it works.

Answer (score 5):

From Calculus by Apostol:

> **Theorem #1:** The set **P** of positive integers $1, 2, 3,...$ is unbounded above.
>
> **Proof #1:** Assume **P** is bounded above. We shall show that this leads to a contradiction. Since **P** is nonempty, **P** has a least upper bound, say $b$. The number $b-1$, being less than $b$, cannot be an upper bound for P. Hence, there is at least one positive integer $n$ such that $n>b-1$. For this $n$ we have $n+1>b$. Since $n+1$ is in P, this contradicts the fact that $b$ is an upper bound for P.
>
> **Theorem #2:** For every real $x$ there exists a positive integer $n$ such that $n>x$.
>
> **Proof #2**: If this were not so, some $x$ would be an upper bound for **P**, contradicting **Theorem #1**.

$\therefore$ The set of real numbers has no upper bound.

Comment: It seems that theorem 2 is used in theorem 1 when we say $n \gt b-1$! Isn't it? :)

Comment: No, it is just a basic deduction that if there was not such a number $n$ then $b-1$ would be an upper bound which is impossible.

Comment: Ah! It seems that I confused myself! You are right. :)

Comment: I love Apostol too :) I wish I have time to read it thoroughly.

Comment: I read the whole first volume about 6 month ago. It was fantastic. I enjoyed reading it. :) When I saw this answer I recalled those days! :)

Comment: Türkçe biliyor musun? :)

Comment: Nope, I don't know Turkish but I love their language! Maybe someday I learnt that!  :)

Comment: I encountered some people from Iran when I was in Toronto and we had a conservation in Turkish which is amazing :) Anyway, it started to be off-topic :)

Comment: Yeah, we Turks in IRAN and many other races.  Good Luck by the way. :)

Comment: I don't know the context of Apostol's proof, but it's clearly overkill here: assume $r = \sup \Bbb R$; since $\Bbb R$ is closed under addition, then $r + 1 \in \Bbb R$, but $r + 1 > r$, contradiction.

Comment: and you gave me (-1) just for this?

Comment: There is not a rule that says "do things in the same way!". From my perspective, this answer is more fun.

Comment: But $b-1$ is an upper bound for P..Because ,if $n\in P$ THEN $n+1\in P$,thus $n+1\leq b\Longrightarrow n\leq b-1$, hence $b-1$ is an upper bound for $p$

Answer (score 4):

Suppose there is such upper bound $r\in\mathbb{R}$.

$r+1>r$ and $r+1\in \mathbb{R}$ since $\mathbb{R}$ is closed under addition.

Comment: So you showed if $r$ is an upper bound then $r+1$ is also an upper bound.  But you will have to do a little more to get a contradiction.

Answer (score 2):

The Archimedian axiom states:

> For every $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$ with $0 < x < y$ there exists a $n \in
>  \mathbb{N}$ such that $y < n x$.

Of course $n x \in \mathbb{R}$, so there is no largest real number $y$.